# ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_str' from 'six' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py)

Tags: python, pip

I am receiving this error on multiple commands, similar to the problem explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727705/pyhton-pip-importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-str-from-six-on-multiple) question. But I am not even able to run it in sudo, non-sudo(if thats a thing) and also root account(I specifically logged into the root account to run this, but failed)

Here is the error I am thrown every time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.freeze import freeze
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .req_file import parse_requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.install.wheel import install_wheel
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.wheel import parse_wheel
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/wheel.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import PY2, ensure_str
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_str' from 'six' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py)
```

Note : I was initially trying to install tensorflow, then other commands like `pip freeze` and `pip uninstall some-package` also threw this error.

I have already tried reinstalling pip without any errors. I am on Manjaro, so i ran

```
pacman -Rcn python-pip
```

and then

```
pacman -S python-pip
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading six?

Comment: @TookieWookie Yes, but got the same error again

Comment: @EbenezerIsaac. Try running code inside virtual environment and installing packages inside virtual environment. That worked for me.

Comment: @SahilDesai Is there no way I can reinstall the whole thing and fix it?

Comment: @EbenezerIsaac I ran code on windows machine and i just did was deleted previous virtual environment and created a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727705/pyhton-pip-importerror-cannot-import-name-ensure-str-from-six-on-multiple#comment109305263_61727705 To upgrade six without pip: download six-1.14.0.tar.gz, extract and run python setup.py install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ pacman -S extra/python-six` did the trick!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you provide a short explanation of how you reached this solution?